# Frequency filter on audio played by AudioTrack in Android?

Tags: java, android, audio, bandpass-filter

I am receiving audio via Bluetooth and also playing it live. I have achieved this by AudioTrack class in Android studio. I used the equalizer class in Android but it cuts the frequency of certain bands only. Eg it only cuts 460-1800 hz on the phone that I am testing. But I want to cut 500hz-1500hz as a bandpass filter does. I have been stuck on this problem for quite a few days now.

I know its possible because I have seen it in other apps eg. [Stemoscope](https://www.stemoscope.com/hi/?Rewrite)

At least point me in some direction. I tried to use TarsosDSP but I can't get any good resources on that and when I used it the output was corrupted and I wasn't able to fix it. I can't seem to find any other library. I can share the code if anyone interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using TarsosDSP only. Was unable to find other better libraries than that